# JQuery | noConflict "Conflict"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a library imported static/assets_admin/js/simple_database.js already working correctly.
But when I want to use another functions of jquery, .change function doesnt work/call anything.

From the resource [w3s](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp),
tried to implement the code like:

```
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var $i = jQuery.noConflict();
        $i(".selectx").change(function(){
        $i.alert("ok")

                                        });
        </script>
```

Not successfull. Changed order of .js files, code blocks, still nothing.
Thank you.

Edit: No any other jquery-xxx version has imported.

```
Full of code:
<script src="/static/assets_admin/js/simple_database.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
{% for u in allusers %}
<tr>
<td>
<select name="userlist[{{ u.id }}]" class="selectx" data-id="{{ u.id }}">
{% if u.is_active %}
<option value="True">True</option>
<option value="False">False</option>
{% else %}
<option value="False">False</option>
<option value="True">True</option>
{% endif %}
</select>
</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
<form method="POST" id="form_users" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
<input id="liveselect" type="text" name="user" value="" />
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
var $i = jQuery.noConflict();
$i(".selectx").change(function(){
var selectedbox = $i(this).children("option:selected").val();
var dataid = $i(this).attr("data-id");
$i('#liveselect').attr('value', selectedbox+"_"+dataid);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `jQuery.alert` is not a documented method, have you defined it?

Comment: alert was for test. Original is: `var $i = jQuery.noConflict();
            $i(".selectx").change(function(){
            var selectedbox = $i(this).children("option:selected").val();
            var dataid = $i(this).attr("data-id");
            $i('#livecheked').attr('value', selectedbox+"_"+dataid);
                                            });`

Comment: Then we need all the relevant code, including the markup, so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please add extra code and HTML to the question

Comment: Does `$i("button").click(...` work if you have a button?  Could be that `$i(".selectx").length === 0` at the time your code runs or it could be a third-part `select` replacement that doesn't fire the change event correctly.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, woks with button onclick

Comment: Then there's (clearly) nothing wrong with `$.noConflict` and it will be your selector / other code.  Check your *rendered* code (as seen by the browser) as it's a js question, the php(?) (and lack of indenting) makes it hard to see what you have.   From what I can tell, your code boils down to [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwd9ypt0/).   Which works fine.

Comment: Just before `$i(".selectx").change` add the line: `console.log($i(".selectx").length))` and let us know the value.  Hint, if it's 0, then that's your issue and change the event handler to `$(document).on("change", ".selectx", function() {...`